# X86-64 NASM calling extern c functions

Tags: c, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

I'm very new to assembly, but know a bit of C. I'm playing around with extern function calls like

```
extern _printf
str db "Hello", 0
push str
call _printf
```

but can't find any tutorials using extern functions except `scanf` and `printf`. How can I call `strcmp`?

Comment: Same way? Why do you think it should be different?

Comment: Sorry i just tried to show what i try to do. But how to proceed? `push stra push strb call _strcmp push 8` and then? where is the result (0/1 i guess in any register)

Comment: Read the *ABI* for your platform. It should describe the calling and return convention. But as far as I know for X86 the return value is usually stored in EAX.

Comment: One approach you can use is to write a C program using the functions and then compile it with the assembler output turned on. This will allow you to see the actual assembler generated by the C compiler when these functions are used.

Comment: Since you are using underscores before names, I have to ask. Are you on Windows or MacOS?

Comment: On windows but its kind of solved, the 0/1 result was in eax and i print it using `push eax push fmt call _printf add esp, 8`

Comment: Are you lookign to generate 32-bit code or 64-bit code running on your MS Windows (I assume you are using a 64-but Windows)

Comment: To be honest i am really very at the beginning so im not quite sure about my whole environment and a little bit confused about all the differences. Im on windows10 64bit and also Debian8 64 bit but right now on windows and i generate 32 bit code ( i think, i use -f elf). I use nasm and gcc.

Comment: Are you running the compiler inside Debian (that is running inside Windows - I assume a VM of some sort or WSL). Virtual machine software would be like VirtualBox, VMWare etc that allow you to run another OS from Windows.

Comment: No i have a dual boot laptop and switch from time to time. But of course i also have a few vms and a workstation too.

Comment: So what compiler are you using to compile this code if you are inside Windows (MinGW, Cygwin)? It matters because if you have a Windows tool chain (GCC and Linker) it will create a Windows Executable. If you compile it on Linux (Debian) it will create a Linux executable. The platform you are targeting matters because the calling conventions are different. As well, on Linux you'd be using `elf64` (for 64-bit binaries) and a GCC that creates native  Windows would be using `win64` (or 32 if creating win32/elf32 if generating 32-bit executables.

Comment: I use in windows Nasm and MinGW and on Linux nasm2.13.03 and gcc8.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer. It is specific to x86-64 though. Please know that when pushing arguments to a function, you usually place the first 6 in registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, and `r9`. The rest get pushed to the stack. The specification for this is called the System V ABI (Note that Windows uses a different convention called the "Microsoft x64 Calling Convention").

```
    segment .data     ; or use .rodata for read-only data.
str1    db      "Hello", 0x0
str2    db      "Hellx", 0x0
fmt     db      "Comparison = %d", 0xa, 0x0

segment .text
    global main
    extern strcmp, printf
    default rel             ; RIP-relative addressing for [name] is what you want.

main:
    ; Create a stack-frame, re-aligning the stack to 16-byte alignment before calls
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    ; Prepare the arguments for strcmp.
    lea rdi, [str1]
    lea rsi, [str2]

    ; Call strcmp, return value is in rax.
    call strcmp

    ; Prepare arguments for printf.
    lea rdi, [fmt]
    mov esi, eax  ; int return value from strcmp -> 2nd arg for printf
    xor eax, eax  ; Indicate no floating point args to printf.

    ; Call printf
    call printf

    ; Return 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS), and destroy the stack frame.
    xor eax, eax
    leave            ; or just pop rbp because RSP is still pointing at the saved RBP
    ret
```

Comment: The good news is the `PUSH RBP` aligns the stack to a 16 byte boundary. You should really be setting AL to the number of vector registers prior to calling a variadic function like `printf` and `scanf`. AL contains the number of vector registers. You have to specify a minimum number you are using to pass arguments. This is important if you are actually passing floating point values to the functions you are calling.

Comment: You might also wish to use the `default rel` directive to make the memory addresses RIP relative (producing PIC = position independent code). That can be beneficial especially on targets where PIC is the default (like MacOS)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I added the directive at the start of the text segment (hopefully that is fine), I didn't know about that! Thank you for letting me know that the number of floats is in `AL`. I was taught it was "in rax", so would just zero the entire register by habit.

Comment: Yes, it is in RAX, that is true so if you set RAX to a value that works as well. However only the lower 8 bits are actually used. So if you put garbage in the upper bits of RAX and the correct value in AL it will still work. The  x86-64 System V ABI makes it clear that only what in AL matters.

Comment: You can actually use `xor eax, eax` to zero all of RAX (and it is a shorter instruction encoding). That works if the destination register of an instruction is a 32-bit register, the CPU automatically extends the result through the entire 64-bit register.

Comment: I've made the change then. I didn't know that either (although I probably could have inspected an example in GDB to find out). I thought that specifying an operation like `xor` would always only affect the "width" of the specified register. (eax does just the lower 32 bits for example). Nice to know!

Comment: That is true except when the destination is a 32-bit register (doesn't apply to any other size). The zero extending (in 64-bit mode) of a 32-bit destination register is automatic in the CPU.If you do `mov eax, 1` for example the value 1 will be stored in EAX and the upper 32-bits of RAX will automatically become zero because EAX (destination) is a 32-bit register. If you do `mov al, 1` it only affects the lower 8 bits in RAX and the rest of the bits in RAX remains unchanged.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ahh.. it doesn't follow the System V ABI does it. I think they use the Microsoft x64 calling convention... I might make a edit.

Comment: Don't change your answer yet, the OP seems to be confused about his environment. Sounds like he's on Windows but he's assembling and linking the code in Debian. I'm trying to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I made a few mistakes here, see comments for details!

Here is a 32bit version (64bit below):

```
SECTION .data
    ; global functions in this file
    global main

    ; extern functions
    extern strcmp

hworld: ; our first string
    db "hello world", 0

hworld2: ; our second string
    db "hello world2", 0

SECTION .text

;=============================================================================
; The program entrypoint
;
main:

    ; int rv = strcmp("hello world", "hello world2");
    push    hworld2
    push    hworld
    call    strcmp

    ; _exit(rv);
    mov     ebx, eax
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
```

Then you can compile it with:

```
nasm -f elf main.s -o main.o
cc -m32 main.o -o hello_world
```

And here is the 64bit version:

```
SECTION .data
    ; global functions in this file
    global main

    ; extern functions
    extern strcmp

hworld: ; our first string
    db "hello world", 0

hworld2: ; our second string
    db "hello world2", 0

SECTION .text

;=============================================================================
; The program entrypoint
;
main:

    ; int rv = strcmp("hello world", "hello world2");
    mov     rsi, hworld2
    mov     rdi, hworld
    call    strcmp

    ; _exit(rv);
    mov     rdi, rax
    mov     rax, 60
    syscall
```

Then you can compile the x64 version with:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.s -o main.o
cc main.o -o hello_world
```

And run it:

```
$ ./hello_world 
$ echo $?
206
```

Comment: Where can i get the resuling 0/1 of strcmp?

Comment: @Rajana It will be in `rax` (Or `eax` if you're on a 32-bit system).

Comment: @Rajana all functions return values are in eax/rax after the function returns

Comment: @user6567423 Maybe you can also add `push rbp; mov rbp, rsp` in the front, and `leave; ret` at the end. This way it creates a proper stack frame if he runs it with `gdb`?

Comment: @Micrified This is 32bit not 64bit, but I understand what you're saying, I think that is outside scope of the question though.

Comment: @Rajana by the way strcmp doesn't return 0/1 it returns the difference between the strings, that's why the return code is 206.

Comment: @user6567423 His title is "x86-64" though... and it would just be good practice. But okay.

Comment: @Micrified Oh whoops, let me add an x86-64 version. I assumed 32bit because he is using push before his call... which isn't how it works in x64-64 so he must have been assembling into 32bit

Comment: @Micrified: strcmp returns `int`, not `long`, so the negative/0/positive return value is only in `eax`, not necessarily sign-extended to `rax`.  glibc's strcmp simply subtracts the two characters that differ.  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-avx2.S.html#128.  Specifically, it zero-extends both bytes to 32-bit, then uses `sub eax, edx`.

Comment: @user6567423: you left out `default rel`, so if you're going to use absolute addressing modes for LEA, it would be more efficient to instead use `mov esi, hworld2`.  Only use LEA for static addresses if you're doing a RIP-relative LEA.

Comment: Also, your 32-bit version violates the ABI: i386 System V requires 16-byte stack alignment before a `call`, same as x86-64 System V.  So you need a dummy `push eax` or a `sub esp, 4` before pushing the args.  It's unlikely that `strcmp`  would fault, or even that it would use stack space at all, but in the general case it's not safe to call library functions without aligning the stack.  Same for your 64-bit version.  A single `push rbp` or `push rcx` or whatever would do the trick.

Comment: Also, `eax=60`/`syscall` is not `exit(3)`, it's `_exit(2)`, which doesn't flush stdio buffers or any other cleanup.  You should normally just `ret` from `main` (after cleaning the stack so ESP/RSP points at the return address again).  You normally only need to exit manually from `_start`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I copy pasted this from one of my asm projects and swapped out a bunch of stuff, in my project I don't link to any standard libraries so I was using _exit() and my main function was actually _start. I never even really thought about all these other things you've mentioned because I was just aiming to show the OP how to make the function call, but that doesn't make you any less correct.

Also I always get caught making the x86 ABI mistake, nice catch. I am going to leave the answer as-is so that people will understand your comments.

Comment: Not everyone reads comments.  You should edit your answer to either change the code or at *least* mention the problems with it.  I guess that one line at the top is barely sufficient, but doesn't make this worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Doesn't seem like OP is going to accept any of the answers anyway, once he figured out how to make the call he disappeared. The other guy gave an answer that conforms to ABI and uses stack frames so just upvote that one.

Comment: `mov  rsi, hworld2` is even worse than `lea  rsi, [abs hworld2]`.  NASM assembles it to 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` with a 64-bit absolute address, instead of 32-bit absolute.  It can easily bottleneck front-end decode, and even slows down uop-cache fetch.  I wrote `mov ESI, hworld2` for a reason: that's 5 bytes, the most efficient way to put a static address into a 64-bit register in position-*dependent* x86-64 Linux code.  (Unlike NASM, YASM assembles `mov rsi,label` to 7-byte `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`, same as a RIP-relative LEA, unless you use `mov rsi, qword hworld2`.)

Comment: See also the bottom of [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427), and the bottom of [Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86\_64 assembly](//stackoverflow.com/a/48597025).